# How do I animate the multiplying of bacteria?

Tags: animation, physics, collision

I need to animate the multiplying of bacteria.

Starting with 1 bactery, this one splits itself in 2 bacteria, these 2 in 4, these 4 in 8, these 8 in 16, etc. This is called exponential growth.

These bacteria also needs a sort of self collision so they can push other ones away. I think that an emitter solution is not possible because particles don't have self collision in Blender (am I right?)

With molecular script this could be solved (self collision) but then you only can work with spheres, not other objects (am I right?)

Maybe it's possible with animation-nodes but to complex for me.

Please take a look at the youtube link with real microscope footage! This will explain what I want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrx7Xg0gkQ4

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the time to thoroughly explain the issue with plain written language. While images and videos are welcome and may help diagnose the issue they should be supplemental to the post text. Also state what you have tried already and where you are having difficulties

Comment: Hi Duarte, I have some extra info. Let me know if this is okay? Thanks!!